# Debugging .htaccess codes

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Right now I am using this code

```
# Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^freevouch\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.freevouch.com/$1 [R=301,L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and with this code:

1. my whole website is redirecting on home page.
2. my contact page doesn't work, it will redirect to my home page.

Comment: For the `Redirect non-www urls to www`, set up a CNAME record

Comment: expected behavior is: all pages redirect to home page, except contact page?

Comment: @h. That's not the same thing. With a CNAME record foo.com and www.foo.com will work equally for serving your website, while a redirect from foo.com to www.foo.com means only www.foo.com is actually serving your website. A DNS CNAME record does not redirect.

Comment: @deceze thanks for clearing that up for me!

Answer (score 0):

this code should be correct for your case:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```